# How to change value in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
a = pd.DataFrame({
    "one":[np.NAN,np.NAN,"e"],
    "two":["a","s","d"],
    "three":[1,2,2]
})
```

|  | one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | a | 1 |
| 1 | nan | s | 2 |
| 2 | e | d | 2 |

I want to change values in column "one" that meet conditions below

1. a["one"] is null.
2. a["three] is 1.

so i used boolean indexing.

```py
a[(a["one"].isnull()) & (a["three"]==1)]
```

|  | one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | a | 1 |

```py
a[(a["one"].isnull()) & (a["three"]==1)].loc[a["one"]!=a["one"], "one"]
```

|  | one |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | nan |

```py
a[(a["one"].isnull()) & (a["three"]==1)].loc[a["one"]!=a["one"], "one"] = "replaced"
```

But dataframe "a" is still "a". Nan value isn't replaced as "replaced". nothing changed.
I want to know why.

Comment: You're assigning to a view of a data frame rather than the data frame itself; that change is then discarded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But dataframe "a" is still "a". Nan value isn't replaced as "replaced". nothing changed. I want to know why.

If check [`evaluation order matters`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters) there is explained you assign to view `a[(a["one"].isnull()) & (a["three"]==1)]` not to original DataFrame.

Correct way is use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for set by boolean mask and columns name:

```
a.loc[a["one"].isna() & (a["three"]==1), "one"] = "replaced"
print (a)
        one two  three
0  replaced   a      1
1       NaN   s      2
2         e   d      2
```